# Oracle Adf & Weblogic Deployment Error

Tags: jsf, weblogic, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, weblogic12c

I am newbie on adf and weblogic.
I have class which includes many jar files. When I call that class from other class that has main method, it runs well .
But I try to call that class from managedBean it returns following error:

> javax.faces.FacesException: #{itResourcesBean.b1_action}:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Thor/API/tcUtilityFactory   at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXCommand.broadcast(UIXCommand.java:190)
>   at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794) 
>   at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
>   at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._invokeApplication(LifecycleImpl.java:1074)
>   at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:402)
>   at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:225)
>   at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
>   at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
>   at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:105)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:502)
>   at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:502)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:327)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:229)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
>   at
>   oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:137) 
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
>   at
>   oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
>   at
>   oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:120)
>   at
>   oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:217)
>   at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:81)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
>   at
>   oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:220)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
>   at
>   weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>   at
>   weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
>   at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)   at
>   weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263) Caused by:
>   javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   Thor/API/tcUtilityFactory   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.MethodExpressionMethodBinding.invoke(MethodExpressionMethodBinding.java:51)
>   at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
>   ... 45 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   Thor/API/tcUtilityFactory   at
>   view.ITResources.connect_ICE_TEST(ITResources.java:83)   at
>   view.ITResources.getITResource(ITResources.java:25)   at
>   bean.ITResourcesBean.b1_action(ITResourcesBean.java:58)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)   at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)   at
>   com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302) 
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.MethodExpressionMethodBinding.invoke(MethodExpressionMethodBinding.java:46)
>   ... 46 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   Thor.API.tcUtilityFactory   at
>   weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:357)
>   at
>   weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:318)
>   at
>   weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:80)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)   at
>   weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:186)
>   at
>   weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:50)
>   ... 56 more   
>   
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   Thor/API/tcUtilityFactory   at
>   javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
>   at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
>   at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:105)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:502)
>   at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:502)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:327)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:229)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
>   at
>   oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:137) 
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
>   at
>   oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
>   at
>   oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:120)
>   at
>   oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:217)
>   at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:81)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
>   at
>   oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:220)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
>   at
>   weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>   at
>   weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
>   at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)   at
>   weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263) Caused by:
>   javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   Thor/API/tcUtilityFactory   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.MethodExpressionMethodBinding.invoke(MethodExpressionMethodBinding.java:51)
>   at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXCommand.broadcast(UIXCommand.java:190)
>   at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794) 
>   at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
>   at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._invokeApplication(LifecycleImpl.java:1074)
>   at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:402)
>   at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:225)
>   at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
>   ... 38 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   Thor/API/tcUtilityFactory   at
>   view.ITResources.connect_ICE_TEST(ITResources.java:83)   at
>   view.ITResources.getITResource(ITResources.java:25)   at
>   bean.ITResourcesBean.b1_action(ITResourcesBean.java:58)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)   at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)   at
>   com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302) 
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.MethodExpressionMethodBinding.invoke(MethodExpressionMethodBinding.java:46)
>   ... 46 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   Thor.API.tcUtilityFactory   at
>   weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:357)
>   at
>   weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:318)
>   at
>   weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:80)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)   at
>   weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:186)
>   at
>   weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:50)
>   ... 56 more

I have added libraries into Libraries and Classpath of project proporties.
Also copied under domain/lib file.

How can I solve that problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem adding jars or libraries under

> C:\Users\youruser\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.2.2.39.61.83.1\DefaultDomain\lib
>   .

It works fine.

Comment: It will work until you deploy on another server. It's not the correct way to do that. See https://community.oracle.com/thread/2267514?tstart=0